# Composer\Downloader\TransportException

Tags: magento2, installation, composer, credentials

Invalid credentials for https://repo.magento.com/archives/magento/module-sales-archive/magento-module-sales-archive-100.1.1.0.zip

I've successfully configured Composer credentials with my Magento Key set using

`composer.phar config http-basic.repo.magento.com <public_key> <private_key>`

and have confirmed that auth.json is effectively updated in Magento root with my keys from Magento Marketplace.

Testing with `composer.phar update --dry-run` Loads repositories, Updates dependencies etc. with the only errors being some requested packages not being found, no probs, I'll get to them ...BUT credentials are fine.

Why when I run `bin/composer.phar install` does Composer proceed to download the bulk of the required dependencies, but fail at this particular module?